# Authorize.net CIM : How to manage multiple card details?

Tags: php, database, authorize.net

I am working on a new project, which needs Authorize.net CIM to be integrated as a payment gateway. User can have multiple cards, Can you please anyone let me know the minimum details I need to save in DB and DB schema for saving the card details?

Comment: Hi John, Please check my question for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3994477/authorize-net-cim-queries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You completely missed the point of CIM. CIM let's you ***store credit card information in Authorize.Net's database***. All you need to be storing is the **payment profile ID they give you for each credit card you store with them**. Then when you want to charge the customer you send them the amount and that payment profile ID and the customer gets charged.

Comment: Hi John, Please check my question for you: http:stackoverflow.com/questions/3994477/authorize-net-cim-queries

Answer (score 0):

You should never **save** Credit Card Details on your Database, let's imagine that someone can access that table? even from your Hosting company...

You should read about **PCI** (Payment Card Industry) **compliance rules**.

I know that you probably want to ease the pain of the user to always write the same number, but I would go with "Please add credit card details as we don't save any information about it" kinda message.

**Regarding the process of multiple cards** ... humm, what can I buy that I need to split up in multiple cards?

Authorize.net allows you to process a payment card at a time, if you have more, you need to queue them.

Comment: Very poor answer - making the checkout easier for the customer should be top priority (if you care about increasing sales), and the whole purpose of the Authorize.net CIM is to store that info securely, so that it can be processed by simply providing an ID, and the transaction details. That's why it exists!